# Can't compile libGDX on Netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to set up a simple libGDX project using Netbeans.  Unfortunately, my compiler can't seem to find any of the libGDX jars to link to.  Isn't Gradle supposed to automatically find and install all dependencies for you?  In any case, the compiler is giving me this when I try to 'run' the desktop project:

```
Executing: gradle run
Arguments: [-c, C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\settings.gradle]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:3: error: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
                       ^
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:4: error: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
                       ^
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:5: error: package com.badlogic.gdx.graphics does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
                                ^
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:6: error: package com.badlogic.gdx.graphics does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
                                ^
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:7: error: package com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
                                    ^
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
public class FightlandGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
                                      ^
  symbol: class ApplicationAdapter
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    SpriteBatch batch;
    ^
  symbol:   class SpriteBatch
  location: class FightlandGdxGame
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    Texture img;
    ^
  symbol:   class Texture
  location: class FightlandGdxGame
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
                    ^
  symbol:   class SpriteBatch
  location: class FightlandGdxGame
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
                  ^
  symbol:   class Texture
  location: class FightlandGdxGame
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:19: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:21: error: package Gdx does not exist
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
           ^
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable GL20
  location: class FightlandGdxGame
C:\dev\starling2\game\2016\fightland\libgdx\core\src\com\kitfox\fightland\FightlandGdxGame.java:22: error: package Gdx does not exist
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
           ^
15 errors
1 warning
:core:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.246 secs



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle run
```

This is code freshly generated from the libGDX project setup utility.  I've made no changes.  I tried changing the source level in the root project to 1.6, but that didn't help.

Another post I read suggested putting the libGDX jars on my classpath, but I'm not sure what these jars are or where to find them.

I remember doing this about a year and a half ago and not running into any problems.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

---

So I was able to somewhat fix my problem by patching my build.gradle file with code taken from a libGDX project generated by an earlier version of the setup plugin.  Basically the build.gradle produced by the lastest version of the gdx-setup.jar had 'dependency' clauses that were completely empty.  I rewrote them to look like

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    }
}
```

Now the desktop project will compile and run.  Haven't tried android yet.  The ios project is giving me error messages about a 'Dependency resolution failure' which I'm not sure how to fix.  I'm kind of curious as to why the setup tool isn't generating any dependency information.

---

And I just tried generating the project again with the lastest version of the setup plugin, and it worked this time.  Not sure why my dependencies were all blank the first time.

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same problem.

the libgdx setup program caused a runtime exception when trying to add third party extensions on my machine.  after the exception occurred, one of the usual generator dialog boxes that usually shows up failed to show up.

- i generated a new project without trying to add any third party extensions and i got a successful project that i can now import into eclipse nicely.